# How to configure dns server for new server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dedicated-server

Scenario:

1. I've purchased a new server with ABC company. In return they've given me two IP Address e.g (10.10.1.1, 20.20.1.1)
2. I've already a domain (www.example.com) working with a different company XYZ.

Q: How i can point my domain to work with newly purchased Server. What are the steps i've to do at both sides, means where i've server and what i've to do where i've domain. What could be the best and easy way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe you need only to change DNS record on your domain for point to new server.

You could do this change in DNS Managements section of your domain hosting.

Comment: i think you didn't understand question as i decided to describe. I have no domains on dedicated server side, i've only IP addresses. how i can change dns to point new server who has only ips.

Answer (score 1):

Does Company XYZ currently provide DNS services for the domain you are wanting to use for your new ABC servers? Do you want to entirely move everything in the domain to now point at your new servers, or do you want to add additional entries (newserver1.example.com, newserver2.example.com) to the domain?

If you just want to add a new record, check with Company XYZ to find what interface they provide for doing this. If you want to move the domain entirely, you have two choices. First, Company ABC may offer DNS hosting as well as server hosting, and you could just ask them to transfer the domain. (You'll need to coordinate with the old company.) Second, and perhaps better, you could move the domain to a dedicated domain registrar / DNS provider. This will probably give you more flexibility and control in the future. I use and recommend [pairNIC](http://www.pairnic.com/)
(they've very tech-savvy and helpful), but GoDaddy, Register.com, etc., and others will also work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you ask the old company. You may have a DNS admin panel, or you may have to open a support ticket, or just do a phone call. There is no one who knows how you can manage your service on company XYZ better than company XYZ.

Technically, you should:
1. upload your site via FTP to the new server (using given IP address)
2. configure virtual host on you new server to respond to name www.example.com
3. change DNS record "www" on company XYZ and make it point to the new IP address.